# react native switch is showing true but value is false why?

Tags: react-native

I use a switch method and If I update the data then I get wrong boolean. Why?

https://reactnative.dev/docs/switch

```
  const toggleSwitch = async () => {
    setGroupActive(prevState => !prevState);
    const d = await updateRoomStatusApi(groupActive);
    console.log(d);
  }
```

Comment: There is not enough code here to determine the issue. Please show code for the `setGroupActive` function, the `updateRoomStatusApi` function, where the `groupActive` variable is set and the `Switch` element itself at the bare minimum.

Answer (score 0):

from the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
> batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
> right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
> componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback))